# Python 3 creating directory name from print output

Tags: python

I have the following code :

```
from lxml import html
import pathlib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import sys
import os
import lxml.html
url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="course-title"]/text()')
names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), names)
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:/'))
for index, name in enumerate(names):
print('{}MY - {}'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))

os.makedirs('names')
```

I want a directory to be created in the location where the script is run. The directory name should be the same as printed output without the number.

Comment: I guess you should make this line os.makedirs('names') as os.makedirs('name') inside you for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you just need to supply the name to `os.mkdir()` (not `os.makedirs()`) which can be done with the same technique that you use to print! Here is an example:

```
from lxml import html
import pathlib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import sys
import os
import lxml.html
url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="course-title"]/text()')
names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), names)
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:/'))
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    print('{}MY - {}'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))
    os.mkdir('{}'.format(name.strip().translate(table)))
```

Comment: I believe "Also create that directory without putting number at the beginning." means not to include index in directory nme.

Comment: You are right. I don't want to include index in directory name. Thanks!

Comment: @Reedinationer, thank you, it works but i still have an issue : 

0MY - Introduction To Content And Endpoint Security

It put me that 0 at the beginning of the line. Thanks!